# Cannot delete volume on drive that was originally a windows installation?

Tags: windows, partitioning, disk-management

I have three drives in my system Disk 0, Disk 1, and Disk 2. Disk 1 and Disk 2 were originally installed in the system, the former was my windows installation and the later my storage drive. I cloned Disk 1 onto Disk 0. I now wish to remove all partitions from Disk 1 (I have previously formatted the drive using the context menu `Format...` option).

To do so I opened Disk Management and assumed I could select "Delete Volume...", though these options are greyed out for the first two partitions on the drive.

[image]

**How do I go about removing the partitions/volumes on this drive to claim all available space in a single partition?**

---

I assume the issue is that the first two partitions on the drive were (and technically still are) "special" Windows partitions and thus the Windows Disk Management utility is "protecting" them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These partitions are of special types for which Windows does not allow deletion.
You need to change their type and do so very carefully - I would verify by
physically disconnecting Disk 1 that its EFI partition is not used for booting.

Here is how to change the type and delete these partitions.
The example below is for the EFI partition. Verify carefully every step.

- Run the Command Prompt (cmd) as Administrator
- Run `diskpart`
- Enter `list disk` and verify which one is Disk 1 (I assume it is the second in the
  list)
- Enter `sel disk 1`
- Enter `list partition` to list the partitions and identify the EFI (I assume the first)
- Enter `sel partition 1`
- Enter `SET ID=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7`
- Finally, enter `delete partition override` to delete it.

For more information, see for example
[How to Delete EFI System Partition in Windows 10/8.1/8/7/XP/Vista](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/delete-efi-system-partition.html).

Comment: This worked. // Note to others, `diskpart` did not list my partitions by the same name(s) seen in Disk Management, I had to cross reference them by size to ensure I had selected the correct ones. In my case I was fine with all partitions being removed (the largest of them being empty and newly formatted), but you may need to do this crosscheck to ensure it. // Also the `diskpart` command `detail <disk/partition>` is useful to ensure you have the correct disk selected (It shows the same names as Disk Management).